# Azure DevOps not showing Tasks on Boards

Tags: azure-devops

We have our board set up with the appropriate columns, however it is only showing Stories. We have individual unparented "Tasks" that we also need to move through the columns. How do we get these visible on the "Boards" page?

Answer (score 10):

I think you can assign these unparented tasks to a sprint. Unparented tasks can be shown in **Sprints Taskboard** from where you can move them through the columns.[image]

It seems it is by design that Boards cannot show standalone tasks. However, you can submit user voice to the product team [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).

Answer (score 5):

I agree that there's a legit reason to have an unparented task show on the board.  We have parent stories on other boards with child tasks assigned to people on other boards and want them to show. This allows the story owner to keep their story on their board to track, but also allows the task assignees to see their work on their own boards. **What's the harm in allowing this capability--that's the better question**.

Answer (score 1):

Tasks should be associated with your Stories - or they will be orphaned, you can do this by clicking on a Task, click the Add Link button under the Related Work section in the lower right of the Task window. Choose Existing Item.. Select Parent as the Link Type then choose what Story you want the Task to be linked to, then Save it.

It should appear on the Boards after that.

If you truly want an Unparented Task you can create the Task under an existing User Story on the board, then click on the Task and remove its Parent and Save it.  It will show up on the board as an Unparented Task.

Comment: In principle for tasks related to stories then that makes sense. But we have legitimate cases where tasks are standalone, such as one-off refactors, renaming of db tables etc

Comment: They will still need a parent otherwise they show up as Unparented, that's what you want?

Comment: Yes they should be unparented but they should also be visible. They are still work items that need doing.

Answer (score 1):

if your tasks are bugs you can do this:
in settings -> working with bugs -> select: Bugs are managed with requirements.
not sure about other tasks.